# the purpose of setting an action when returning a result by setResult

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the example code from [Training for Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html#ReturnResult)

```
 //Create intent to deliver some kind of result data
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);

finish();
```

When we return a result from sub-activity, normally we only need to set Extra or Uri data. What's the  purpose of specifying a custom action here ?
Update:

Say we want to  open the Gallery app to select an image to use in our app.

Invoking Gallery app

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Returning the result

```
   Intent result = new Intent();              
   result.setData(_Uri.parse("content://result_uri");
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
   finish();
```

handling the result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            // Do something with the image here 
    }
}
```

I didn't set  "com.example.RESULT_ACTION" in the example code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `startActivityForResutl` mean you are expecting a response from second/sub activity and `onActivityResult` will be triggered when user return back to the previous activity.

`onActivityResult` has 3 parameter and one of them is an `intent` and if second/sub activity haven't called `setResult` function then you will receive `intent` as `null` in the previous activity

In your case the `result` intent will never be delivered you the previous activity if you don't call `setResult` funtion

First Activity

```
Intent intent = new (..., secondActivity);
..
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Second Activity

```
....
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));

//setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result); this is not there
finish();
```

First Activity

```
... OnActivityResult(int response, int request, Intent data)
               //                                      ^^^ will be null because 
               // setResult was not called in second activity so to get data intent 
               // you have to call setResult
```

**Note :** if you don't want any result then use `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult` and there will be no need to call `setResult` in second activity and `OnActivityResult` function will not be triggered

---

Update :

```
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION",
Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));
```

`com.example.RESULT_ACTION` : mean what is the type of action which is performed , which is in this case is a result action

it is similar to the `action` field of `intent-filter`

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        ^^^
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so that you can verify the the type of action performed e.g in activity result you can do

```
if(data.getAction().equals("com.example.RESULT_ACTION"))
 { // do this}
else if(data.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SEND"") {
   // do something here}
```

and obviously the can be done using request and response code but this is useful when the data or action take place between two apps instead of two activities

`content://result_uri` is just an example again in docs , but this mean , the type of data mean details about data associated with an intent

For example : if you want to send images using intent to open image with app installed on the system you use

```
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
```

where `image/*` describes the type of file that is an image

e.g [getData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()) which give you the data/file resource on which intent is working on mean it give the [URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) which can be further used to validate the data type.

So this is very helpful when communication take place between two apps but while using `startActivityForResult` within same app then you can simply identify result type using request and response codes

Comment: My question is  the purpose of specifying a custom action here, in this case setting "com.example.RESULT_ACTION". I don't understand why we need to set that, and I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @user3591494 that is not necessary , let me update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, Pavneet. I think this has cleared things up. But I still don't completely understand why it is useful  for two apps not two actions ?Can you elaborate on that or give me another example?

Comment: @user3591494 lets say you use intent to open image , there can be many app which can open images so OS kind of run the activity tracking system and check which apps has activity with `image/*` support , so the list will be shown to user , in short you can use `send` intent then apps like whatsapp and other shown in list to perform the action

Comment: I think that you are talking about app chooser where there is more than one app that responds to the implicit intent.I don't see how that has anything to do with the issue we are discussing. you  haven't explained why setting result action is useful between two apps.

Comment: @user3591494 As i mention in the answer and in your example too,  this `com.example.RESULT_ACTION` explains the the type of action mean action was successful and u can verify it using `if` as i shown and about  `Uri.parse("content://result_uri")` it is a path location of some file or resource in database which inserted through content provider , so in this case , assume some app request to insert file and your intent is telling the caller that action is successful and this `Uri.parse("content://result_uri")` is URI of inserted file.

Comment: But just like you said in the answer this can be done using request and response code , so I don't see how that will be useful  whether its for the two activities or two apps.

Comment: @user3591494 whatsup app won't be a part of my app or inbuild gallery app, you should study contentprovider , URI and MediaStore usage , then things will be more clear after reading these and one more things you can take action on the basis of request and response code but OS need to know what is the type of action should be performed and Activities which can show images registered with `Image/*` across android OS and that's how OS decide which can handle image send intent ,not on the basis of some integer constants and read about `mimetype` too

Comment: it seems you are talking about how system handles implicit intent, while I'm talking about how to send back the result, and how the hosting activity handles the result. If result is in the form of URI , we can just create an empty intent. result.setdata(Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);finish();in the host activity use getdata() to retrieve  the URI data.  we don't need to set the result_action at all.I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: @user3591494 there are many ways to do one things , in short when you can set data at the time of creating intent then why would you call separate function (although you can , doesn't mean you have to) ,if you want the same functionality , one thing can be achieved in many ways you do 1+2 or 4-1 , it's depends on you

Comment: that's the point.I think so ,too.It's just an option .you can choose to use between two activities ,OR two apps.So I don't think it's useful only between two apps.that's what i'v been trying to say.Thank you so much,Pavneet .

Answer (score 0):

> Each incoming intent specifies only one action and one data type, but
>   it's OK to declare multiple instances of the `<action>`, `<category>`, and
>   `<data>` elements in each `<intent-filter>.`

It says whatever activity or sub-activity you are sending your results from to  activities or subActivities, it needs to define an action for that `Intent` again for the activity you're sending your results to, due to its `<intent-filter>` defined for proper handling that `Intent`.

So it is more like a `<intent-filter>` safe approach.